# rstudio notebook pandoc.exe out of memory

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, rnotebook

When I'm using R notebook and always getting error message like

```
'pandoc.exe.. out of memory'.
```

And the code chunk seems to freeze and cannot be executed. 
Can someone educate me how it works and why it happens? I tried to google the solutions. seems not that obvious.  I wonder if there is any easy way to increase the 'notebook memory size'.   I still have plenty of space on my ram...Thanks.